# Pass Data from Child Window to MainWindow TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

In this example, `MainWindow` has a button that opens `Window2`.

`Window2` has a button that writes "Hello, World!" to `MainWindow` textblock.

Project source: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jegeguhycs1mewu/PassData.zip?dl=0

[image: Pass Data]

---

What is the proper way to pass data from `Window2` to `MainWindow`?

```
private MainWindow mainwindow;
public MainWindow mainwindow { get; private set; }
public Window MainWindow { get; set; }
private object mainwindow { get; private set; };
private MainWindow mainwindow = ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow);

this.mainwindow = mainwindow;
```

---

### MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Open Window 2
    private void buttonWindow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2(this);
        window2.Left = Math.Max(this.Left - window2.Width, 0);
        window2.Top = Math.Max(this.Top - 0, 0);
        window2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

### Window 2

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    private MainWindow mainwindow;

    public Window2(MainWindow mainwindow)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.mainwindow = mainwindow;
    }

    // Write Message to MainWindow
    private void buttonMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainwindow.textBlockMessage.Text = "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem or what are you trying to optimize ? Your question is pretty confusing.

Comment: I'm using `private MainWindow mainwindow;` in `Window2`. It works, but is this the correct way?

Comment: what happens when you click Window2 button? Mainform will be hidden and displayWindow2 form, and if you click Message button in Window2 Form, Window2 Form will be hidden and display Mainform with Hello world in textbox right?

Comment: @BùiQuangThành The window does not get hidden, it just opens on top. When `Window2` passes "Hello, World" I don't believe a new instance is created or hidden, `MainWindow` just updates.

Comment: @BùiQuangThành If you want to download the source, you can run it and see how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is very implementation-based and depends heavily on what you want `Window2` as a class to do.

---

```
private MainWindow mainwindow;
```

This is acceptable.

```
public MainWindow mainwindow { get; private set; }
```

This would work but doesn't respect naming conventions because it's a property. Usually you'd use this for encapsulation of a field or for easy access to a computed value.

```
public Window MainWindow { get; set; }
```

This is not acceptable in your context because `Window` does not contain a `textBlockMessage`.

```
private object mainwindow { get; private set; };
```

This also wouldn't work for the same reason as above.

```
private MainWindow mainwindow = ((MainWindow)System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

This would work and would even let you not keep a field for the reference to the `MainWindow` instance in your `Window2` instances. Still needs to get that `MainWindow` everytime you click the button however.

---

Another interesting way to do what you're doing however is to simply pass the handler to the child windows at instanciation:

**MainWindow**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Open Window 2
    private void buttonWindow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 window2 = new Window2(); // No need to give a reference to the child window anymore
        window2.setClickHandler((obj, ev) => {
            textBlockMessage.Text = "Hello, world!"; // Direct access to the textblock.
        });
        window2.Left = Math.Max(this.Left - window2.Width, 0);
        window2.Top = Math.Max(this.Top - 0, 0);
        window2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**Window2**

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void setClickHandler(RoutedEventHandler handler)
    {
        // The handler is given to the click event.
        buttonMessage.Click -= handler;
        buttonMessage.Click += handler;
    }
}
```

And with that your `Window2` class has no need to know `MainWindow`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I think `private MainWindow mainwindow;` will cover mostly what I need, as I call and change many different types of controls on `MainWindow`. ComboBox, TextBox, Button, etc. The `Application.Current.MainWindow` works when using for Invoking a Control from another Thread, but sometimes it does not work normally.

Comment: @MattMcManis Yes, having it that way lets any `Window2` have full access to the `MainWindow` instance. However you should make sure that it truly suits your needs, because in most cases you want to avoid having such circular references (`a` references `b` & `b` references `a`). My handler alternative and the other answers avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

The 'proper' way usually depends on what your needs and circumstances are. But in general, using a delegate to pass data between windows is a common and standard practice.

Lets say the data you want to pass is a string. In your Main window, you want to create a delegate that lets you pass a string. Then you create an instance of that delegate type and subscribe a method that matches. Then when you open your secondary window, you pass that delegate to your secondary window.

```
public delegate void DataTransfer(string data);

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DataTransfer transferDelegate;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        transferDelegate += new DataTransfer(DataMethod);
    }

    public void DataMethod(string data)
    {
        // Do what you want with your data.
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window2 win = new Window2(transferDelegate);
        win.Show();
    }
}
```

Now, when you invoke that delegate in your secondary window, the `DataMethod()` of your Form1 gets called, and so you can pass information between windows.

Your secondary window implementation should look like this:

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    DataTransfer transferDel;

    public Window2(DataTransfer del)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        transferDel = del;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string data = "Hello, World!"; // Your string data to pass.
        transferDel.Invoke(data);
    }
}
```

As you can see, when you invoke the delegate that was passed, it calls the corresponding method in your main program.

One stand out advantage of this method is that you don't need to pass an instance of MainWindow to your Window2, you simply use delegates and subscribed methods to pass data between the two instances of windows.

Comment: This is ok for OP's specific implementation. However if the button click action gets any more complex (i.e. change multiple textblocs or do different actions on the `MainWindow` instance, this might not be preferable.

Comment: @Mat it's still doable, and in fact still there is no major drawback imo. If you want to change multiple textblocks, you could either send a `List<string>` or a different defined data structure. If you want multiple actions be done, you can create separate delegates for that. Like I said at the beginning of my post, exact implementation depends heavily on needs, and unless you _really_ need to pass an instance of a `Window` class, this is a preferable method I think; only the necessary data is passed between windows.

Comment: Yep, depends a lot. But even in hypothetical scenarios, having to structure the data first and then get the data from it in the receiver is a step that I'd avoid. See my answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You could declare a delegate in Window 2 and pass a function that can be executed when the button is pressed in window 2.

```
 public delegate void SendMessage(string Message);
 public SendMessage mainWindowDel = null;
```

Make your constructor that accepts the delegate

```
 public Window2(SendMessage del)
        {
            mainWindowDel = del;
        }
```

create window 2 by passing a function as the parameter

```
 public void showMessage(string Message)
 {
                if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Message))
                textBlockMessage.Text = Message;
 }
 private void buttonWindow2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
            // Open Window 2
            //Window2 window2 = new Window2(this);
            Window2 window2 = new Window2(showMessage);
            window2.Left = Math.Max(this.Left - window2.Width, 0);
            window2.Top = Math.Max(this.Top - 0, 0);
            window2.ShowDialog();
  }
```

call the delegate when they press the button

```
// Write Message to MainWindow
        private void buttonMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           mainWindowDel("Hello, world!");
        }
```

Comment: I will have to experiment with this on my larger project.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably set the datacontext of the MainWindow to an object that you could also pass to Window2 when it's created and set it's datacontext to the same object.

In that object could create a string property that could be used in both windows. And if you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface both windows would know when that string is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach

**MainWindow**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool DisplayText(string displayText)
        {
            txt_Main.Text = displayText;
            return true;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window2 win2 = new Window2(DisplayText);
            win2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

**Window2**

```
 public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        private Func<string, bool> mainWindowMethod;

        public Window2(Func<string, bool> displayMethod)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.mainWindowMethod = displayMethod;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.mainWindowMethod("Hello World");
        }
    }
```