# c# between windows form send data

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

I have WinForm form named `form1`

I open `form1`, and when I click a button it opens `form2`. In `form2`, I then select a `GridRow`.

When I select a row in `form2`, I want this value to be passed back to `form1`, closing `form2` in the process.

İn similar questions, answers contain `form1.show()`, but in my case, I would rather have `form1` remain open through this process.

Code for `form2`

```
private void datagridItemList_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
       ProductCode = datagridItemList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       ProductName = datagridItemList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       ProductCount = datagridItemList.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45747145/pass-data-from-child-window-to-mainwindow-textblock/45747491#45747491
AND this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx

Comment: 1,135,245 c# questions.  This has been asked.  Consult the legion of links under **Related**  Then please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: thanks @Hybridzz  ı solved with your suggest..

Comment: great. Please do a research before you post.